# Error CODE : procedure has too many arguments specified

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a this SQL Server stored procedure. When I execute it, I'm getting this error:

> SQL Server procedure has too many arguments specified

How can I solve this problem? Code is shown below.

When my stored procedure is working, I need to do if record exist update then add record.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO 
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 
GO 

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Insert_MS] 
    (@SID char(20),
     @CREATE_DATETIME char(14),
     @MODIFY_DATETIME char(14),
     @CREATOR_SID char(20), 
     @MODIFIER_SID char(20), 
     @MARK_DELETED char(1), 
     @TARGET_SID nvarchar(20),
     @TARGET_CODE nvarchar(50),
     @UNIT nvarchar(100),
     @SPECIFICATION nvarchar(1000),
     @MATERIALS_SUBCAT nvarchar(1000),
     @SORT int,
     @SET_UNIT nvarchar(1000),
     @ENABLED char(1),
     @MARKET_TYPE nvarchar(2)
    ) 
AS 
BEGIN 
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM [dbo].[M_S] 
               WHERE [MARKET_TYPE] = @MARKET_TYPE 
                 AND [TARGET_CODE] = @TARGET_CODE 
                 AND [TARGET_SID] = @TARGET_SID) 
    BEGIN 
        --update existing record 
        UPDATE [dbo].[M_S] 
        SET [MATERIALS_SUBCAT] = @MATERIALS_SUBCAT , 
            [SPECIFICATION] = @SPECIFICATION, 
            [UNIT] = @UNIT
        WHERE [MARKET_TYPE] = @MARKET_TYPE 
          AND [TARGET_CODE] = @TARGET_CODE 
          AND [TARGET_SID] = @TARGET_SID 
    END 
    ELSE 
    BEGIN 
        --insert new record 
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[M_S] ([SID], [CREATE_DATETIME], [MODIFY_DATETIME], 
                                 [CREATOR_SID], [MODIFIER_SID], [MARK_DELETED], 
                                 [TARGET_SID], [TARGET_CODE], [UNIT], [SPECIFICATION], 
                                 [MATERIALS_SUBCAT], [SORT], [SET_UNIT],
                                 [ENABLED], [MARKET_TYPE]) 
        VALUES (@SID, @CREATE_DATETIME, @MODIFY_DATETIME,
                @CREATOR_SID, @MODIFIER_SID, @MARK_DELETED,
                @TARGET_SID, @TARGET_CODE, @UNIT,
                @SPECIFICATION, 
                @MATERIALS_SUBCAT, @SORT, @SET_UNIT,
                @ENABLED, @MARKET_TYPE) 
    END 
END
```

Then my aspx.cs code is here

```
cnn.Open();

insertSql += " INSERT INTO [dbo].[MATERIALS_SUBCAT] ([SID],[CREATE_DATETIME], [MODIFY_DATETIME],";
insertSql += "  [CREATOR_SID], [MODIFIER_SID], [MARK_DELETED],[TARGET_SID], [TARGET_CODE],";
insertSql += "  [UNIT], [SPECIFICATION], [MATERIALS_SUBCAT], [SORT],[SET_UNIT], [ENABLED], [MARKET_TYPE])";
insertSql += " VALUES (@SID, @CREATE_DATETIME, @MODIFY_DATETIME, @CREATOR_SID, @MODIFIER_SID, @MARK_DELETED, @TARGET_SID, @TARGET_CODE, @UNIT, @SPECIFICATION,";
insertSql += "@MATERIALS_SUBCAT, @SORT, @SET_UNIT, @ENABLED, @MARKET_TYPE)  ";

SqlCommand cmdStoredProcedure = new SqlCommand("Insert_MS", cnn);
cmdStoredProcedure.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

for (int k = 0; k <= dt_sheet.Rows.Count - 1; k++)
{
    cmdStoredProcedure.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SID", dt_sheet.Rows[k]["SID"].ToString());
    cmdStoredProcedure.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CREATE_DATETIME", dt_sheet.Rows[k]["CREATE_DATETIME"].ToString());
    cmdStoredProcedure.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MODIFY_DATETIME", dt_sheet.Rows[k]["MODIFY_DATETIME"].ToString());
    cmdStoredProcedure.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CREATOR_SID", dt_sheet.Rows[k]["CREATOR_SID"].ToString());
    cmdStoredProcedure.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MODIFIER_SID", dt_sheet.Rows[k]["MODIFIER_SID"].ToString());
    cmdStoredProcedure.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MARK_DELETED", dt_sheet.Rows[k]["MARK_DELETED"].ToString());
    cmdStoredProcedure.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TARGET_SID", dt_sheet.Rows[k]["分類代碼"].ToString());
    cmdStoredProcedure.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TARGET_CODE", dt_sheet.Rows[k]["品項代碼"].ToString());
    cmdStoredProcedure.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UNIT", dt_sheet.Rows[k]["單位"].ToString());
    cmdStoredProcedure.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SPECIFICATION", dt_sheet.Rows[k]["規格"].ToString());
    cmdStoredProcedure.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MATERIALS_SUBCAT", dt_sheet.Rows[k]["品項名稱"].ToString());
    cmdStoredProcedure.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SORT", dt_sheet.Rows[k]["SORT"].ToString());
    cmdStoredProcedure.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SET_UNIT",null);
    cmdStoredProcedure.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ENABLED", dt_sheet.Rows[k]["ENABLED"].ToString());
    cmdStoredProcedure.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MARKET_TYPE", dt_sheet.Rows[k]["MARKET_TYPE"].ToString());

    cmdStoredProcedure.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cnn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Show your asp.net code too. The error is clear enough you are passing too many parameters to stored procedure!

Comment: Cross verify the code behind and your database whether you have not missed out or added any parameters.

Comment: @Zaki already added aspx.cs code

Comment: do you want to execute the stored procedure within the loop? you add the same parameters several times for each k

Comment: If you want to execute same stored procedure for each row, then move the ExecuteNoneQuery() inside loop too.

Comment: @Zaki im already moved, but also not working.

Comment: Did you move these two lines too : SqlCommand cmdStoreProcedure = new SqlCommand("Insert_MS", cnn);
                        cmdStoreProcedure.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

Comment: @Zaki and Koryu thanks for your suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you want to execute the stored procedure each time you loop through your sheet. Moving the Command into the loop and use "using" to easy dispose the command each time, like this:

```
 for (int k = 0; k <= dt_sheet.Rows.Count - 1; k++)
      {
        using (SqlCommand cmdStoreProcedure = new SqlCommand("Insert_MS", cnn))
        {
          cmdStoreProcedure.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
          cmdStoreProcedure.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SID", dt_sheet.Rows[k]["SID"].ToString());
          cmdStoreProcedure.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CREATE_DATETIME", dt_sheet.Rows[k]["CREATE_DATETIME"].ToString());
          cmdStoreProcedure.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MODIFY_DATETIME", dt_sheet.Rows[k]["MODIFY_DATETIME"].ToString());
          cmdStoreProcedure.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CREATOR_SID", dt_sheet.Rows[k]["CREATOR_SID"].ToString());
          cmdStoreProcedure.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MODIFIER_SID", dt_sheet.Rows[k]["MODIFIER_SID"].ToString());
          cmdStoreProcedure.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MARK_DELETED", dt_sheet.Rows[k]["MARK_DELETED"].ToString());
          cmdStoreProcedure.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TARGET_SID", dt_sheet.Rows[k]["分類代碼"].ToString());
          cmdStoreProcedure.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TARGET_CODE", dt_sheet.Rows[k]["品項代碼"].ToString());
          cmdStoreProcedure.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UNIT", dt_sheet.Rows[k]["單位"].ToString());
          cmdStoreProcedure.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SPECIFICATION", dt_sheet.Rows[k]["規格"].ToString());
          cmdStoreProcedure.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MATERIALS_SUBCAT", dt_sheet.Rows[k]["品項名稱"].ToString());
          cmdStoreProcedure.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SORT", dt_sheet.Rows[k]["SORT"].ToString());
          cmdStoreProcedure.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SET_UNIT", null);
          cmdStoreProcedure.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ENABLED", dt_sheet.Rows[k]["ENABLED"].ToString());
          cmdStoreProcedure.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MARKET_TYPE", dt_sheet.Rows[k]["MARKET_TYPE"].ToString());
          // connection.Open();
          cmdStoreProcedure.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
      }
      cnn.Close();
```

Comment: Thansk for your Solution.

Answer (score 2):

Your code tries to access SQL Commmand: `Insert_Materials_SubCategory`
Whereas the shown procedure is called: `Insert_MS`